# jinja2 Ansible filter dictionary

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I've been doing ansible for a while, but have recently started doing some more advanced things such as pulling data to drive actions from outside sources.  This has resulted in me having to dig a little deeper into how ansible allows logic and parsing of variables, requiring me to dig a little into jinja2.

In my playbook I am attempting to pull data in from etcd, allowing me to construct authorized sudo spec files, which I then pass onto a role to add to the appropriate systems.

My datasource, in addition to storing data that is needed to construct the specs has metadata used for auditing and logging purposes.

A key aspect of my datasource is that no metadata, i.e. that user XYZ had password less sudo for a period of 10 days, should be deleted when access is removed.  So many aspects have a state field that may be **active**, **inactive** or in the case of sudo specs **grant** or **revoke**.

I have successfully constructed a lookup that pulls back a dictionary similar to below - which I then parse using the subsequent ansible statements.  I am able to succcessfully process and extract all data except for groups/users that have their specs in a **grant** state.

When specs are in a "grant" state, I need to extract the **linuxName** field, to be passed onto the role that configures sudo.

I have tried a number of variations of filters, most of which end in me getting a reject or similar message, or a NULL value instead of the list of values that I want.

Anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Sample Data

```
ok: [serverName] => {
    "sudoInfraSpecs": [
        {
            "infra_admins": {
                "addedBy": "someUser",
                "commands": "FULL_SUDO",
                "comment": "platform support admins",
                "dateAdded": "20180720",
                "defaults": "!requiretty",
                "hosts": "SERVERS",
                "name": "infra_admins",
                "operators": "ROOT",
                "state": "active",
                "tags": "PASSWD",
                "users": {
                    "admingroup1": {
                        "addedBy": "someUser",
                        "dateAdded": "20180719",
                        "linuxName": "%admingroup1",
                        "name": "admingroup1",
                        "state": "grant"
                    },
                    "admingroup2": {
                        "addedBy": "someUser",
                        "dateAdded": "20180719",
                        "linuxName": "%admingroup2",
                        "name": "admingroup2",
                        "state": "grant"
                    }
                }
            },
            "ucp_service_account": {
                "addedBy": "someUser",
                "commands": "FULL_SUDO",
                "comment": "platform service account",
                "dateAdded": "20180720",
                "defaults": "!requiretty",
                "hosts": "SERVERS",
                "name": "platform_service_account",
                "operators": "ROOT",
                "state": "active",
                "tags": "NOPASSWD,LOG_OUTPUT",
                "users": {
                    "platformUser": {
                        "addedBy": "someUser",
                        "dateAdded": "20180719",
                        "linuxName": "platformUser",
                        "name": "platformUser",
                        "state": "grant"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Ansible snippet

```
- name: Translate infraAdmins sudoers specs from etcd into a list for processing [1]
  set_fact:
    tempInfraSpecs:
      name: "{{ item.value.name}}"
      comment: "{{ item.value.comment }}"
      users: "{{ item.value.users | list }}"
      hosts: "{{ item.value.hosts.split(',') }}"
      operators: "{{ item.value.operators.split(',') }}"
      tags: "{{ item.value.tags.split(',') }}"
      commands: "{{ item.value.commands.split(',') }}"
      defaults: "{{ item.value.defaults.split(',') }}"
  with_dict: "{{ sudoInfraSpecs }}"
  when: item.value.state == 'active'
  register: tempsudoInfraSpecs

- name: Translate infraAdmins sudoers specs from etcd into a list for processing [2]
  set_fact:
    sudoInfraSpecs_fact: "{{ tempsudoInfraSpecs.results | selectattr('ansible_facts','defined')| map(attribute='ansible_facts.tempInfraSpecs') | list }}"
```

Rough Desired output dictionary:

```
sudoInfraSpecs:
      - infra_admins:
          addedBy: someUser
          commands: FULL_SUDO
          comment: platform support admins
          dateAdded: '20180720'
          defaults: "!requiretty"
          hosts: SERVERS
          name: infra_admins
          operators: ROOT
          state: active
          tags: PASSWD
          users:
              "%admingroup1"
              "%admingroup2"
      - ucp_service_account:
          addedBy: someUser
          commands: FULL_SUDO
          comment: platform service account
          dateAdded: '20180720'
          defaults: "!requiretty"
          hosts: SERVERS
          name: platform_service_account
          operators: ROOT
          state: active
          tags: NOPASSWD,LOG_OUTPUT
          users:
              "platformUser"
```

Comment: Are you able to modify the format of the data pulled from etcd? If you returned a list of flat objects, maybe with a `name: infra_admins`, it would be much easier to `selectattr()` on them. With the current format, if looping through the list of results, you'll need to extract the top level key name for each object, eg.: `{% for i in sudoInfraSpecs %} {% if i[i.keys()[0]]["state"] == "active" %} {{ i }} {% endif %} {% endfor %}`

Comment: Am I right in thinking that doing something like this is more appropriate for the .j2 file I use as the template then within the playbook?

Comment: Yeah it would definitely be far easier to hide all this complexity in a template / defaults file - then you could use a few temporary variables, etc. I wanted to do this in a one liner but it'll look awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this by creating a custom filter for use in my playbook that parsed the nested dictionary that makes up users:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def getSpecActiveMembers(my_dict):
    thisSpecActiveMembers = []
    for i, value in my_dict.iteritems():
        if value['state'] == 'grant':
            thisSpecActiveMembers.append(value['linuxName'])
    return thisSpecActiveMembers

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'getSpecActiveMembers': getSpecActiveMembers
        }
```

This ends up flattening the users from the source listed above, to the desired output.